# Jquery UI date from and date to field validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

can someone help me on this, I am having problems on validating datepicker from jquery, I need to validate two dates from and to, the thing is the from date is disabled and becuase of that the minDate options doesnt seem to work.. if there's anyway I can check on the validy of the To-Date field that will not be less than the From-Date. Thanks to those who will help me.

Comment: are you using jquery validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out, I have put the .datepicker method after the complete function of ajax since I am populating the data from an ajax request. so instead of putting the .datepicker on .ready function.

Here's the sample code I created:

```
function GetInfo() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "test",
        data : "{}",
        contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(response) {
 },
complete : function(e) {
$("#id-of-the-DOM-end-element")
            .datepicker(
                    {
                        minDate : new Date($("#id-of-the-DOM-start-element").val()),
                        'http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif'
                    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function CheckDate()
    {
      var StartDate= document.getElementById('txtStartDate').value;
      var EndDate= document.getElementById('txtEndDate').value;
      var eDate = new Date(EndDate);
      var sDate = new Date(StartDate);
if(EndDate=="")
        {
        alert("Please Enter EndDate");
        }
       else
      {     
    if(StartDate!= '' && StartDate!= '' && sDate> eDate)
      {
      alert("End Date is greater than or equal to the Start Date.");
      return false;
      }
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that there is some value inside from date text field which is disabled (as question is not properly quoted) .

Though from date textbox is disabled you can get value of textbox by using js/jQuery like `$("#fromID").val();`

Use this script to restrict the minimum date of toDate text box:

```
<script>
  var min=$("#fromID").val();
  $(function() {
    $( "#toID" ).datepicker({ minDate: min });
  });
  </script>
```